# Basic useradd question

Tags: useradd

I added one user with myname(prashant) but i had not set any password for same user account.
Still when i reboot(runlevel5), i os asked mi for password for same user account. I tried to login with without password as i not set, still authentication failure msg display. how it is possible?

OS : Cent os 6.4
I added more two users also but not beneficial.
Please can any one tell me the reason and way to login with same user.

Comment: It sounds like you want to set an empty password for your user. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

From the `useradd(8)` man page:

> ```
>    -p, --password PASSWORD
>        [...] The default is to disable the password.
> ```

The way to allow login is to assign a password using `passwd`.

Comment: To allow login by using passwd it is ok, but when i need to use this command. I mean after just useradd or when. Because i added user already and restarted system. I am now using this command but it is setting password. Kindly let me know how i disable the password of created account and while creation of new account using useradd command how i disable the password. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Prashant Your question is unclear. Do you want to set passwd or not?

Comment: The question is clear: the OP ***wants to login*** and cannot because the system is asking for a password, even though none was set.

Comment: Yes G-Man is correct, i just added user with useradd command and when i reboot machine it shows me to enter password for same user.